# git-gui on Ubuntu doesn't show new directories

Tags: git, git-gui

I use git gui on Ubuntu 10.04 (git-gui version 0.12.0.64.g89d6) to manage my commits (staging, unstaging, checking diffs) and I like it a lot.  However it does not show any new files or directories that I have created, even though 'git status' on the command line shows them as untracked. I have to explicitly do 'git add' on the untracked files before I run git gui, and then they show up as staged changes.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening? Or what the right way is to add untracked files from inside git gui? Other comments I've seen about git gui suggest that this is not normal behaviour but I can't find any option that might affect it.

Comment: I found the answer: My core.excludesfile config item was set to "~/.gitignore".  It turns out that this format causes the git-ls-files command that git-gui issues to fail.  When I replaced the config entry with the full path to my .gitignore, then the untracked files appeared as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do these new directories contain files?  Git cannot track an empty directory as far as I know.

You mention that this is happening with untracked files as well.  I am running the same version as you on Ubuntu and new files show properly in git gui.  Did you check to ensure that .git/info/exclude or .gitignore isn't hiding them from you?

Comment: To clarify: If I add a new file in a tracked directory, the file does not appear in git gui. If I create a new directory with files in it, neither the directory nor the files appear.  And since (in both cases) the new file/directory is listed by 'git status' as "untracked", and I can add them from the command line with "git add", these are not excluded or ignored files - just plain C/H files.